# Finding a Context Free Grammar for Different No. of a and b AND Different No. of b and c

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

The question is from my homework: Is the language $\{a^ib^jc^k\mid i,j,k\geq0\land i\neq j \land j \neq p\}$ a context-free language (CFL)? If yes, please provide a context-free grammar for it. I found this question quite challenging, so I decided to post it here.

My attempts:

1. First I tried to show the language is not a CFL using the pumping lemma. I tried with $a^kb^{2k}c^k$, $a^kb^{k+1}c^{k+2}$ but all failed to pump out of the language.
2. I understand that pumping lemma says nothing about the language is context-free. But I failed to prove it / disprove it.
3. Then I tried to look for a context-free grammar for it. But my grammar is always possible to generate a word that is not in the language.
4. I tried to search for an answer, but I just found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29932077/7109257) for $\{a^ib^jc^k|i,j,k\geq0,i\neq j \lor j \neq p\}$. The "and" and "or" sure makes a difference, so I don't think this answer is helpful.

Comment: The symbol $\vee$ means "OR" and $\wedge$ means "AND", so there is a bit of inconsistencies between your title and post.

Comment: @Rhiddishi Please check if my edit is OK. By the way, it is usually unnecessary to say "please forgive me", "first time", "edited", "thank you" in a post on StackExchange.

Comment: since they are either obvious, implied, expected or more distractive than helpful.